# Open a sqlite3 database from an io.BytesIO stream?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

In Python3.4, is it possible to open an SQLite3 database from an io.BytesIO stream?

Something akin to:

```
with open("temp.db", "rb") as openf:
    byte_stream = io.BytesIO(openf.read())
sqlite3.connect(byte_stream)
```

The short story is: I have a stream (`byte_stream`) that *is* the sqlite database file. I can't do the following for security reasons (can't create an unencrypted file):

```
with open("temp.db", "wb") as openf:
    openf.write(byte_stream)
sqlite3.connect("temp.db")
```

Is there some lower-level API for sqlite3 that I haven't been able to find? I assume that `sqlite3.connect` simply calls `open()` at some point and opens the file as a byte stream anyway. I'm simply trying to skip that `open()` step.

Comment: How did you get the byte stream?

Comment: The SQLite3 python bindings use the SQLite3 C library, and likely the `sqlite3_open_v2` function, which takes a file name (or a VFS URL, but that's pretty advanced and IDK if Python exposes that API).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo is correct, and if the implementation is checked nowhere `open()` is actually called - see [`Modules/_sqlite/connection.c:102`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Modules/_sqlite/connection.c#L102) for actual implementation (in C).

Comment: Yeah, I was looking around at the C implementation, trying to see if there was some way to do it. Didn't find anything at first glance, but I was hoping someone else knew something. As for the VFS URL, that's exposed but not really documented. See https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect (I think.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with Python's `sqlite3` module.

If you were using APSW, you could try writing your own [virtual file system](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/vfs.html).

Comment: I was afraid of that. What about creating an in-memory database `sqlite3.connect(':memory:')` and then somehow replacing that with the data from the stream? Or importing the data from the stream? Is something like that possible?

Comment: No, you cannot get at the underlying bytes of an in-memory database.

Comment: Link not actual.

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite *open*-ing it so you can run SQL queries, but you can use https://github.com/uktrade/stream-sqlite to get at all the rows in the file.

If you have an io.BytesIO instance, you can use `iter` to convert it to an iterable of `bytes` that stream-sqlite needs:

```py
import io

import httpx
from stream_sqlite import stream_sqlite

url = 'https://www.parlgov.org/data/parlgov-development.db'
byte_stream = io.BytesIO(httpx.get(url).read())
bytes_iter = iter(lambda: byte_stream.read(4096), b'')

for table_name, pragma_table_info, rows in stream_sqlite(bytes_iter, max_buffer_size=1_048_576):
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

(Disclaimer: I was heavily involved in the development of stream-sqlite)

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.11, sqlite3 has a method called [deserialize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.deserialize) on the connection object which takes the bytes of a database and deserializes it. You can use it for your purpose like so:

```py
import sqlite3


with open("temp.db", "rb") as openf:
    db_bytes = openf.read()

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.deserialize(db_bytes)
```

Note that as mentioned in the documentation:

> This method is only available if the underlying SQLite library has the deserialize API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sqlite_deserialize` API that is exposed as part of [APSW](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/) that can accept the serialized `bytes` of a SQLite database:

```py
import apsw
import httpx

url = "https://data.api.trade.gov.uk/v1/datasets/uk-trade-quotas/versions/v1.0.366/data?format=sqlite"

with apsw.Connection(':memory:') as db:
    # deserialize is used to replace a connected database with an in-memory
    # database. In this case, we replace the "main" database, which is the
    # `:memory:` one above
    db.deserialize('main', httpx.get(url).read())
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM quotas;')
    print(cursor.fetchall())
```

The above doesn't use an io.BytesIO instance as in the question, but you can call `read` on one to get the bytes if you have one:

```py
import io

import apsw
import httpx

# For working example purposes, constructing io.BytesIO from an HTTP response
url = "https://data.api.trade.gov.uk/v1/datasets/uk-trade-quotas/versions/v1.0.366/data?format=sqlite"
byte_stream = io.BytesIO(httpx.get(url).read())

with apsw.Connection(':memory:') as db:
    db.deserialize('main', byte_stream.read())
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM quotas;')
    print(cursor.fetchall())
```