# Query an existing/downloaded SQLite database in Python in memory, without having to write it to disk first

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I would like to query a SQLite database, downloaded from a remote sever for example via HTTP, in Python, without having ever written it to disk.

I see you can start a blank SQLite database in memory using the magic name `:memory:` https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html. And I see you can copy from a disk-backed SQLite DB to an in-memory one, say using [iterdump](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.iterdump). But... I would like to populate a `:memory:` database with the contents of a `bytes` instance that contains the database, without ever having written those `bytes` to disk fist.

My reason: it seems unnecessary to have it all in memory, have to write it to disk, and then read it back to memory, so it's a general "keeping the number of steps down" in my process.

Comment: It would be neat to be able to do it with [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html), but `sqlite3.connect` only accepts path-like objects, not file-likes.  Maybe there's a way to do it at the C level?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47745836/5320906) points out that sqlite has a native mmap capability.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I'm not that familiar with mmap, but doesn't it need the file to be written to disk first?

Comment: Ah yes, I thought you could pass it bytes, but apparently not.

Comment: Sqlite has a serialization API that does what you want, but the python sqlite library is very minimalist and doesn't provide access to it.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Indeed there is a way in C: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/serialize.html and https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/deserialize.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sqlite_deserialize` API that is exposed as part of [APSW](https://rogerbinns.github.io/apsw/) that can accept the serialized bytes of a SQLite database:

```py
import apsw
import httpx

url = "https://data.api.trade.gov.uk/v1/datasets/uk-trade-quotas/versions/v1.0.366/data?format=sqlite"

with apsw.Connection(':memory:') as db:
    # deserialize is used to replace a connected database with an in-memory
    # database. In this case, we replace the "main" database, which is the
    # `:memory:` one above
    db.deserialize('main', httpx.get(url).read())
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM quotas;')
    print(cursor.fetchall())
```

This is a version of the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/77731273/1319998

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't support queries, but you can use https://github.com/uktrade/stream-sqlite to access the contents of a downloaded/downloading SQLite file without having it written to disk.

Taking the example from its README:

```py
from stream_sqlite import stream_sqlite
import httpx

def sqlite_bytes():
    with httpx.stream('GET', 'https://www.parlgov.org/data/parlgov-development.db') as r:
        yield from r.iter_bytes(chunk_size=65_536)

for table_name, pragma_table_info, rows in stream_sqlite(sqlite_bytes(), max_buffer_size=1_048_576):
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
```

(Full disclosure: I was heavily involved in the development of stream-sqlite)